# Is Hashtable.entrySet() thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it safe to iterate over the set returned by `Hashtable.entrySet()`? What about `Hashtable.values()` and `Hashtable.keySet()`?

What I intent to do: I want update the entries of a Hastable while the table is used by different other threads. For this I have to iterate over all entries currently in the map. It's not important if any entries added/removed from other threads during the iteration are handled or not. Synchronizing on the Hashtable is not an option because the update may take to long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, iterating over the views of a Hashtable is not safe in the face of concurrent modification. From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) (emphasis mine):

> The iterators returned by the iterator method of the collections returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are fail-fast: if the Hashtable is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, **in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails** quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future. The Enumerations returned by Hashtable's keys and elements methods are not fail-fast.

jabu.10245 is correct that a ConcurrentHashMap is more appropriate, and does meet your requirement of allowing iteration while concurrent modification is occurring.

Answer (score 3):

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html):

> Unlike the new collection implementations, Hashtable is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use HashMap in place of Hashtable. If a thread-safe highly-concurrent implementation is desired, then it is recommended to use ConcurrentHashMap in place of Hashtable.

Better use a [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the Iterators of `ConcurrentHashMap` allowed for concurrent modification.

Answer (score 0):

I think we're just going to quote the documentation of `Hashtable` at you.

> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, **it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness:** the fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs.

I think the docs say it all:  You can't depend on the iterator telling you when you've modified a `Hashtable` incorrectly.  Either synchronize on the `Hashtable`, or use a different class.